# Mock function return in node.js test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm new to testing in node.js and I would like to mock the return of a specific function call in a process that looks like the following.

```
doSomething(function(err, res){
    callAnotherOne(res, function(err, result){
        getDataFromDB(result, function(err, docs){
            //some logic over the docs here
        })
    })
})
```

The function that I want to mock is the getDataFromDB() and specifically the documents (using MongoDB) that it returns.
How could I do something like this with mocha?

Part of the code, strip from the logic in between, is the following:

```
filterTweets(item, input, function(err, item) {
    //Some filtering and logging here

    db.getTwitterReplies(item, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            return callback('Failed to retrieve tweet replies');
        }

        //Do some work here on the item using the result (tweet replies)

        /***** Here I want to test that the result is the expected ****/

        db.storeTweets(item function (err, result){
            //error checks, logging
            callback();
        });
    });
});
```

Based on the amount of twitter replies (function call "getTwitterReplies"), I will modify my object accordingly (didn't include that code). I want to see if based on different replies result, my object is constructed as expected.

p.s. I also checked into sinon.js after some searching and I managed to mock the return of a callback (by writing some testing code outside my project) but not the return of a callback of a nested function call.

Comment: I can't really think of a solution to this without seeing an example of how it's all tied together.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding the code I want to mock.

Comment: The scoping of require() can provide a way to do easy dependency injection in tests with sinon.js without introducing a lot of extra function parameters. I'll follow up with a more extensive answer along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this category of problem:

First create a "config.js" that wraps the dependencies that you'd like to inject. This will become your container.

```
 var db = {
    doSomeDbWork : function(callback){
      callback("db data");
    }
 };

 module.exports = {
   db: db
 };
```

From there, you can call config dependencies like so:
    var config = require('./index/config');
    config.db.doSomeDbWork(function(data){
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' , data:data});
    });

And in your tests, inject a mock/spy easily:

```
var config = require('../routes/index/config');
config.db = {
  doSomeDbWork : function(callback){
    callback("fake db data");  
  }
};
var indexRouter = require('../routes/index');
indexRouter.get('/');
```

Because the require call refers to the same config module exports, the changes made to the config in the spec will be reflected where ever they are imported via require()

Comment: I 've tried mocking the modules, but it is not that flexible. I will have to create mock modules for every single test scenario. On top of that there are case that I want to use the unmocked methods of a module. I'm looking at "proxyquire" at the moment and it actually seems to do the job for me.

Comment: Proxyquire looks perfect for this scenario actually. Similar to this approach without the extra module wrapper overhead.